# Asking for input thrice when it should only do twice in c

Tags: c

I found out after reading online that if i use "%c "(with a trailing space) that scanf would read newline character but on trying it out its asking me for input thrice rather than just twice . Please tell me where i went wrong and why I am getting the answer that i am getting now

```
main()
{
 double e = 5.32 ;
 int strlen , strlen1 ;
 char Test_string , Test_string2 ;
 scanf("%c " , &Test_string ) ;
 scanf("%c " , &Test_string2 ) ; 
 printf("\n%c" , Test_string) ;
 printf("\n%c" , Test_string2) ;
 printf("Success") ;
 return 0 ;
}
```

Output-

```
P
A
U

P
ASuccess
```

Comment: Instead of asking us to ignore extra variable declarations, just remove them from the question.  Removing superfluous code is part of constructing a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: @Blindy I heard that in Sam Beckett's voice.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yeah, Sam Beckett is notorious for talking about C functions used as variables lol

Comment: @Blindy That's probably how the quantum leap works.  Undefined behavior leading to overwriting memory locations outside of his own.

Comment: What @ChristianGibbons said. I fixed it for you now, but don't tell us what we should ignore. Don't show us anything we should ignore.

Comment: Just for clarification for the OP: The name `strlen` is also the name of a function in the C standard library. It is generally not a good idea to use such names for something else, as these names will conflict as soon as you do `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I missed a few variables. Remove the declarations of `e`, `strlen` and `strlen1` or motivate their existence.

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%c ")` is going to attempt to consume one character and then all possible whitespace.  When the input stream begins with `P\nA\n` and has not yet been closed, `scanf` is going to continue to try reading from the input stream until it sees either the end of input or it sees a non-whitespace character.

If you are new to C, don't use scanf.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use scanf for keyboard input.

Comment: For further reading: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is known to be a poor man's parser, and `%c` conversion is the harder to correctly use.

What you want here is to use the white space directive to skip any white space (including newlines) **before** reading the next non white space character. But to obtain that, the blank must precede the `%c`:

```
 ...
 scanf(" %c" , &Test_string ) ;
 scanf(" %c" , &Test_string2 ) ;
 ...
```